# Reference of reference in vector<>::push_back()?

Tags: c++

Why does `push_back()` take `Object&&` as parameter, and not simply a reference of the object, like `Object&`?

What is this operator?

Comment: It is the move operator. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics

Comment: Good question. Allthough I have been programming in C++ quite a lot I actually never saw such construct.

Comment: Lookup `std::move` please!

Comment: It's not a "reference to a reference", such things doesn't exist. You might want to learn about ["Move semantics and ***rvalue references*** in C++11"](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html),

Comment: @EdHeal `Object&&` is a type, not an operator

Answer (score -2):

That would be the move operator, wich is new since c++11. This allows you to move objects into your vector instead of copying them. Google search for a more detailed descriptiob of the move operator.

Comment: It isn't an operator. It is an rvalue rference.